PyLance Auto-Completion with Docker
I'm using PyLance in Visual Studio Code to work on a Dockerized Python project, and there are certain dependencies that is very complex to be built on MacOS, so I dockerized the project and now it works fine.
The problem is, since I didn't build/install the library locally on my OS, PyLance is not able to detect such library and provide auto completion.
Is there any hack to make PyLance detect & read packages in Docker containers, or simply not installed locally (e.g., a cloned git repo, without being installed)?
